# Fetch text from other website and redirect to domain.tld/?id=

Tags: php, jquery

I want to get body content from an external page as plaintext.

Then pass the value for API call. eg.

`xyz.com/?id=<plaintext from ext. page>`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$content = file_get_contents('xyz.com/?id=<plaintext from ext. page>');
```

Comment: $content = file_get_contents('abc.com/page'); how to pass the content eg. xyz.com/?id=$content;   @mishanon

Comment: $content = file_get_contents('xyz.com/?id=' . $content);

Comment: both are different domains.  1. Get body content and store in variable and then pass the variable with url call as parameter.

Comment: I guess, easy variant it use base64 function to encode body content. and decode it in php script